# How to make a new environment behave like an existing environment?

Tags: environments

I wish to create an environment that behaves alternately like a footnote, an endnote or a comment (i.e. hidden). For starters i've defined an environment "note" thus:

```
\newenvironment{note}
 { \footnote{ }
 { } }
```

expecting that now

```
Hello\begin{note}world\end{note}
```

would expand into

```
Hello\footnote{world}
```

but this doesn't seem to be the case. The document compiles with no warnings, and the pdf output does in fact contain a footnote, but the footnote is empty.

What might the problem be, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Isn't it easier defining a `\pfootnote` command that you can redefine at will?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a new environment, it has to have the form

```
\newenvironment{<env>}
  {<begin env>}% \begin{<env>}
  {<end env>}% \end{<env>}
```

where `<begin env>` is execute at `\begin{<env>}` and `<end env>` is executed at `\end{<env>}`. Using your approach causes confusion, even though you *think* it might work:

```
\newenvironment{note}
  { \footnote{ }
  { } }
```

For example, even though you think `\begin{note}` should expand to `\footnote{` and `\end{note}` should expand to `}`, thereby embracing the enviroment contents, TeX creates the environment at definition time, and the braces in your definition is ambiguous. In fact `\begin{note}` actually expands to `\footnote{ } { }` since the balanced pair of braces are matched at the same level/depth.

Your way around this predicament is to capture the environment contents *first* - made possible with the aid of [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ), and then pass that to `\footnote`. The environment contents is grabbed inside a macro called `\BODY`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron{note}{\footnote{\BODY}}% Environment-form of \footnote
\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{world}. Hello\begin{note}world\end{note}.

\end{document}
```

Note that, even with the environment-like approach, you're still limited in terms of what can be contained within (no verbatim content, for example).

Answer (score 12):

Probably the simpliest way is to use `\NewEnviron` from the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package and define your `note` environment as

```
\NewEnviron{note}{\footnote{\BODY}}
```

Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{note}{\footnote{\BODY}}

\begin{document}

Hello\begin{note}world\end{note}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know there was a package that makes it so simple!